# Distributing marbles into buckets for maximal colour sharing

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph-theory, np-complete, np-hard

i've got a problem that feels very much like it's NP-hard but I would love some help proving it primarily.

Secondary to that, if an optimal polynomal time algorithm can be proposed that is even better, although even good "greedy" approximations are fine.

Given M marbles, B buckets and each bucket having capacity K, where M = BK , find some distribution of the marbles that maximizes the number of colours that are shared. colour A and colour B are considered to be shared if they appear together in the same bucket. That is, we can increase a share count for each unique pairing seen of some A and some B (A != B), provided they are seen in the same bucket. We want to optimise for this share count.

An example python function which might be used to score such an algorithm:

```py
def score(aBuckets):
    seenPairs = set()
    for myBucket in aBuckets:
        for colourA in myBucket:
            for colourB in myBucket:
                if colourA != colourB:
                    seenPairs.add((colourA, colourB))
    return len(seenPairs)//2
```

The distribution of colours is known for a given problem, and can be sorted and added in any order you desire

The colours are provided as some array, where each element at an index represents a colour count. The sum of each element gives you M. We cannot make any assumptions about how this array is distributed, just that it is provided.

Example:

| BucketId | Colours |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | A, C |
| 1 | A, C |
| 2 | B, D |
| 3 | B, D |

M = 8, B = 4, K = 2

Colour array: 2,2,2,2

Clearly, this is non-optimal since we may swap C in bucket 1, with D in bucket 2 and achieve a better outcome (more colours shared).

Any insight into this problem should be infinitely appreciated, Thanks :)

Comment: @harold your understanding is exactly correct, its now just about finding some algorithm in polynomial time to find the optimal colour pairings if possible (or proving if its NP-hard)

Comment: @ravenspoint The problem says, *"The distribution of colours is known for a given problem..."* Which I take to mean that we have an array of `M` marbles of known colors.

Comment: @btilly your understanding is almost just about right, although I'll definitely make this input more clear. It is an array where each index would correspond to a colour. The sum of each element in the array would give you M

Comment: Just edited post to make it more clear

Comment: If I were approaching this by hand, I'd first distribute all `c` of each color into the first `c` slots, allowing them to be filled past `K`.  I would then frame the problem as the redistribution of over-capacity marbles into new slots.

Comment: Could you write down the actual objective function, as an actual function, I have no idea what English words mean anymore at this point

Comment: Hi Harold, just added more details about what we are optimising for maybe a minute after you asked :)

Comment: @harold I have added a python function to the example that I would be trying to optimise. Python function isn't optimised and is just used to illustrate the point. If you have a way I can write that as a mathematical expression , i'm also happy to change this.

Comment: Wrote this function In a rush and has some issues I'll fix later
1. The same colour should not be considered a pair and 2. Should half its length at the end so A->B is considered the same as B->A

Comment: @ravenspoint this is absolutely not the case , and I'm not sure where you get the idea. The answer you posted , you claimed it was optimal in the comments. Id have no problem accepting a greedy answer if that's what the answer claims it is. Your answer was just code with no explanation, and wasn't optimal like you claimed.

Comment: @NightShade the scoring function as you described it is different from the one you provided. In one `red red red blue` distribution has the same score as `red red blue blue` distribution, it the other it has not.

Comment: Besides, this question is off topic on [so]. You should try [computer science](https://cs.stackexchange.com) (but even there, they might consider that you are just asking them to do the job for you, not to help you to do it). [so] is for the coding part (and you haven't even specified a programming language, proving that coding is not your problem). [so] is, for example, when you have the algorithm, have coded it in python, and don't understand why it fails.

Comment: Also your last example is strange. You say "we could swap C in bucket 1 with D in bucket 2 and achieve better color share" How so ? There are still no color shared at all after that. How is it better?

Comment: So in the example, previously we have the following shared colours: A-B, C-D making for a total of 2. After the swap we have A-B, A-D, B-C B-D - improving it to a total of 4. We should look at the number of unique pairings